# how to set different authentication requirements in pam policies for different users or groups?

Tags: security, pam, fido-u2f

I'm trying to set up a linux development environment that is both secure and convenient, and after setting up passwordless login and 2-factor authenticated `pam_u2f`, I had the idea to create different user accounts with different authentication requirements.

in the configuration files located at `/etc/pam.d/`, authentication methods tend to be user/group agnostic, for example:

```
auth required pam_u2f.so  authfile=/etc/my_yubikeys cue
```

can you specify users or groups so that, for example an admin account or members of the group `wheel` requires 2 factors to login(password and something else), while other users require one?

Comment: How can you ask me a "special" authentication before you trust that I'm me (already authenticated)?

Comment: authentication comes in 3 flavors, something you know (password) is only one of them. in the context of pam(_yubico/_u2f) has sort of support for something like this with options to not require it if a user doesn't have 2fa setup.

Comment: also while the above line has the `authfile` stored in a user agnostic location, most often yubikey (setups) have the authfile stored at user level(same with google authenticator), so pam already has the ability to check user level stuff before the user has been fully authenticated.

Comment: people already have passwordless setups where fido2 is the only authentication method(i did it yesterday when testing config settings), what I'm trying to do is have that as an option for unprivileged accounts, but require 2 methods for admin accounts, which would rely on pam having some way of being aware of users or groups, or accessing a root only file which is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`pam_succeed_if`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if) module to skip other PAM modules in the stack given certain user criteria. For example you could create a group `noyubikey` and add the following to your PAM configuration:

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user ingroup noyubikey
auth required pam_u2f.so  authfile=/etc/my_yubikeys cue
```

Updated to answer your question:

> could I use this to require a number of authentication methods, where
> any one of them are optional. sort of like "there are 3 possible
> authentication methods, but you need to use any 2 of them"

This should be possible with a a [**substack** and custom controls](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.conf). E.g. you could require a substack like this:

```
[success=ignore default=1] # first module
[success=done default=1] # second module if the first one succeeded
[success=ignore default=die] # second module, if the first one failed
[success=done default=die] # third module now has to succeed
```

Note: I am only showing the controls for clarity's sake.

You'd want to use a substack here because it isolates the done/die actions from the rest of your stack.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the link to the documentation. I'm not sure if this is possible, but could I use this to require a number of authentication methods, where any one of them are optional. sort of like "there are 3 possible authentication methods, but you need to use any 2 of them"

Comment: @JoshuaFerguson I've updated my answer.